# JS/HTML: Convert decimal user input to color and fill box with it

Tags: javascript, html, function, colors, colorbox

I am currently working on the following problem: I would like to have three fieldsets for user input and their input will be transfered into a table that has four rows: one with the hexadecimal value of the input of fieldset "red", one with the hexadecimal value of the input of fieldset "green", one with the hexadecimal value of the input of fieldset "blue" and the last one with a little box that portays the given decimal value as their color.

This is how far I have come:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Colortheme</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="seite">
  <h1 id="header">Portray Colors</h1>
  <div id="content">
  <br>

  <!-- Create form for user input. -->
  <form name="color">
  Red: <input type="text" name="c"> <br>
  Green: <input type="text" name="c"> <br>
  Blue: <input type="text" name="c"> <br> 
  <input type="button" value="Paint" onclick="javascript:drawmycolor();">
  </form>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  a = Number(document.color.c.value);

  // Converts decimal into hexadecimal values.
 function getHexadecimalValue()
 {
    return parseInt(a, 10).toString(16);
 }

 // Creates table with hexadecimal values and color
 function drawmycolor()
 {
   if (a >= 0 && a < 255 && Math.floor(a) == a)
   {
     var thecolor = getHexadecimalValue(a);
     document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">');
     document.write('<tr><th>Hexadecimal Red</th><th>' +
     'Hexadecimal Green</th><th>' +
     'Hexadecimal Blue</th><th>' +
     'Color</th></tr>');
     document.write('<tr><td>' + getHexadecimalValue(a) + '</td><td>' + 
     getHexadecimalValue(a) + '</td><td>' + 
     getHexadecimalValue(a) +
     '</td><td style="background-color:"thecolor"</td></tr>');
     document.write('</table>');
   }
   else
   {
     window.alert("This value does not refer to any RGB color.")
   }
 }

 </script>

<noscript>
<p>Da Sie die JavaScript Funktion Ihres Browsers deaktiviert haben, können
Teile diese Seite leider nicht angezeigt werden</p>
</noscript>
</center>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<p> Zurueck zum <a href="./Startseite.html">Start</a>.</p>
</div>
<p id="footer">
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
  src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401" alt="Valid HTML 4.01 Strict" 
  height="31" width="88"></a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first problem I have is, that if I put in a value like 6, that should clearly work with the if-conditions, I still receive an alert that tells me the values are wrong.

The second problem is the one with the little color box I would like to have in the last row of my table. How can I enter one there and how can I make sure that the color the box has is the one of the decimal the user put in?

Thank you already for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when this line is executed:

```
 a = Number(document.color.c.value);
```

`a` is always `undefined`, since this line is run outside of an event handler. It should be part of `drawMyColor`:

```
function drawmycolor()
  {
  a = Number(document.color.c.value);
  ....
```